# Client socket maintaining queue/pooling

Tags: java, sockets, connection-pooling

I am trying to create a client socket connection, when a new request is created a connection is established & data transfer takes place. Is there any way that once the Connection is created it will be open for all time ? If yes then how can create it & also how can I identify what request is sent & got the response for the same request?

Looking forward for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a connection for all time, by not closing it. However the trick is detecting when a connection has failed. e.g. the client/server has restarted.

If you want to match requests to responses you can use a request id, but a much simpler approach is to only send one request at a time per socket, that way the response you get is for the request you just sent. You can use more than one socket in a thread if this is required.

Comment: Thank you, But in my case say client Connection time out is 30 secs, so how will I handle this in case say there are multiple request send & I dont get response for 30 secs then suddenly I get the response so for one of the request all the data (response) will be accumalated. Also if I don't close the connection the number of process for that socket will be open, & may lead to heap.

Comment: If you have a server which works a particular way, you need to use the appraoch that server supports. i.e. I would ask the developers/support staff of the server.  I can only tell how you would do it if you are the developer of both ends. It is possible your server does not support durable connections with streaming results and the only way to fix it is to change the server. BTW: Is the server a commonly know product?

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you for the response. I am trying to connect from a web application to another server(Socket server) which supports one connection. The socket server supports one connection from WEB , that means once the connection is open its should not close for any request. So my doubts is how can I keep this connection alive for n request & then handle the same getting response for that request it self? (Synchronize it) Also what if I have two application accessing the same Socket server (How do I maintain one connection)? What if the web system get clustered?